# Group by and get one of column value in group by based on certain condition of other column in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have below PostgreSQL table, which is small sample of huge table

```
employee

emp_id | salary | rating | increment_year
--------------------------------------
28      3000      1         2023
25      2000      2         2023
30      1500      1         2021
28      1000      3         2022
32      1200      1         2023
23      1550      1         2023
30      2500      3         2022        
30      3000      2         2023
```

I want make a PostgreSQL query which does
 `group by emp_id` and returns `emp_id, sum(salary), get rating value based on latest increment_year, latest increment_year that was selected to get rating value`

Example query result sample

```
emp_id | sum_salary | selected_rating_on_latest_increment_year | selected_increment_year_to_get_rating
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28       4000         1                                         2023

value goes on for every emp_id
```

I have to use group by due to certain pre existing condition. So doing it by group by, is mandatory for me, if it's possible.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a verbose alternative you may use a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) for `selected_rating_on_latest_increment_year` value instead of a JOIN.  The rest would come from the `t` CTE that does have a `group by`.

```sql
with t as
(
  select emp_id, sum(salary) sum_salary, max(increment_year) increment_year
  from employee
  group by emp_id
) select emp_id, sum_salary, 
         (
           select rating from employee
           where emp_id = t.emp_id and increment_year = t.increment_year
         ) selected_rating_on_latest_increment_year,
         increment_year
 from t;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uJAHp46mm29JG6ULUBmXg2/0)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       emp_id,
       SUM(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id),
       FIRST_VALUE(rating) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY increment_year DESC),
       MAX(increment_year) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id)
FROM employee;
```

Update based on your request to use group by:

```
SELECT e2.*, e1.rating 
FROM employee e1
JOIN ( SELECT emp_id,
              SUM(salary) salary,
              MAX(increment_year) increment_year
       FROM employee
       GROUP BY 1
       ) e2 USING (emp_id, increment_year)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I have to use group by due to certain pre existing conditions. Can you please help me do it by group by.